# TabControl - Making a TabItem appear on top of the Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, tabcontrol

I have a custom style for a `TabControl`.  As part of the style I want the selected TabItem to appear on top of the Content.  Currently the `TabPanel` has no `ZIndex` set so it appears underneath the content (desired behaviour).

What I cannot seem to get working is making the selected TabItem appear on top of the Content.  Setting `Panel.ZIndex` on that `TabItem` seems to have no effect

```
<TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Panel.ZIndex="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,10,2,0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
```

TabItem Style (important bit):

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#fff"/>
</Trigger>
```

Here is an image of what I currently have (left) and what I would like (right).  Note that the shadow on right of the `TabPanel` is coming from the `Border` surrounding the `ContentPresenter` on the `TabControl` template itself. Hence I want the selected `TabItem` to appear on top of it!

[image]  vs  [image]

P.s. Bonus marks if anyone knows how to make the top left and bottom left corners of the `TabPanel` rounded - I gave up trying to get that to work

Comment: could you add an image of what you're expecting against what you're currently having cos I can't really follow your question.

Comment: Well what you're looking for seems to be the default behavior for me on a `TabControl` with no custom Style's set. All WPF seems to do for that is when the `TabItem` is selected, it's Header ends up taking 2 pixel's more than normal in Width or height based on orientation to end up covering the Border between it and the `Content`.

Comment: The default behaviour is actually that the `TabPanel` "header" is above the `Content`.  I could do this but then I lose the drop shadow on the unselected items

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you change the **ControlTemplate** of the **TabControl**?

The problem seems to be that the default **ControlTemplate** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137(v=vs.110).aspx) has the **ContentPresenter** declared after the **TabPanel**, effectively forcing it above in Z-order.

A simple solution may be to simply copy this from the link provided, paste it in and reverse the order of the **TabPanel** and the **Border** elements (some adjustments may be required as the **Border** may now sit on top of the **TabPanel** altogether, blocking it's view).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">

    <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">

                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- VisualStateManager stuff... -->

                    <Border Grid.Row="1" ... >

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>

                    </Border>

                    <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" ... />

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

</Style>
```

For rounded corners on your **TabPanel** s, I would again advise looking at the **ControlTemplate** for the **TabPanel** class.